# Why can't I create a txt file after having just deleted it?

Tags: c#, logging, io, delete-file

My program creates a log file when it starts. The user has the option through settings to "clear the log" which calls a method to delete the log file.

```
        //calls for a YesNo prompt to delete log or not
        result = objectMessageBox.ReturnDeleteLogPrompt();

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //throw prompt
            if (File.Exists(objectLog.GetLogLocation()) == true)
            {
                try
                {                        
                    //delete the log file
                    File.Delete(objectLog.GetLogLocation());                        

                    //throw balloon tip saying log was cleared
                    ShowBalloonTip("LogCleared");
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error thrown deleting log: " + ee);
                    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(ee.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Because I have deleted the log file entirely I need to then recreate it. So I call a method that has this:

```
try
        {
            //we create a new log file so it seems that the log has just been cleared
            objectLog.CreateLog();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured while clearing log:\n" + ee);
        }
```

But when it attempts to recreate the log file it throws an error that says:

> "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '~~' because it is being used by another process."

So it seems that during my call to delete the file it keeps accessing it? Do I need to dispose of something when I call the `file.delete`?

Comment: have you tried calling dispose on the objectLog after you delete it?

Comment: Are you sure there is really no other application that has the log file open?  Try using procmon and procexp from http://live.sysinternals.com/ to check which apps access the file.

Comment: Windows Sucks. The file entry should have been gone.

Comment: Rename the file to a random unused name before deleting it.

Comment: You could try to open the file with `FileShare.None` and then closing it, just before deleting it, just to see if the file is in use before deleting it.

Comment: Are you sure that the log file does in fact get deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting and recreating the same file, can you just clear it out?

Something like this should work for you:

```
FileStream f = File.Open(@[filename], FileMode.Create);
f.Close();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as others did, however it did provide me a solution to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Well in effect, FileMode.Create overwrites the existing file with a new one, so you could argue that it handles the deletion and recreation in a single step.  But I understand your point that it's curious as to why the file is still locked after the .Delete and for how long.  That solution I have to leave to others.  Glad to have helped you solve your immediate problem though.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the details, but there are numerous reasons for why a filename isn't immediately available for recreation after deleting an existing file:

- The delete operation is still pending by the operating system
- An antivirus program or similar security feature opened up the file in response to it being deleted, for pre-deletion analysis
- An antivirus program or similar security feature already had the file open while you were using it, and is still in the progress of responding to your deletion request

Mercurial had this problem on Windows as well. If you executed one command that locked the repository (which was done using temporary files), and then immediately executed another command that either needed to lock, or at least ensure no lock was present, it could fail with the same type of error, the file was in use, even though this was two distinct processes and the first had already exited.

In other words, the timeline was as follows:

- hg.exe instance #1 starts up, locks the repository by creating the temp file
- hg.exe does what it needs to do
- hg.exe deletes the file, then exits
- hg.exe instance #2 starts up, attempts to lock the repository, fails because file is in use

Their hack to "fix" this was to simply pick a random filename that wasn't used in the directory, rename the file to that name, and then delete it. This did not solve the problem of the file lingering for a short while, but it did free up the filename and make it available for new files right away.

Comment: I never noticed the `FileShare.Delete` "Allows subsequent deleting of a file" before I noticed this post :) From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx: "the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed."

Answer (score 4):

There already is an accepted answer, but perhaps someone finds this useful (or laugh at it if I missed something obvious again and wasted my time completely)

I had the impression that `File.Delete` would either delete the file and then return, or otherwise throw an exception - until I read this thread.

The windows API mentions that by calling `DeleteFile` the file is "marked for deletion on close" since it allows calling delete on an open file. After a file is marked for deletion, an attempt to open it will fail as "Access denied". When the last handle for this file is closed, the file is actually deleted.

If windows actually deletes the file before returning from the last `CloseHandle` call on the file, in theory this code would guarantee that the file is deleted below the `using` block:

```
using (File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

The `File.Open` would fail if another process currently has the file open.

Note the difference here that `File.Delete` even succeeds if a file does not exist (unless the directory does not exist).

Comment: This is very interesting. I'll up vote it because I don't know if it is sound enough to be the selected answer. I'll let others chime in though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use System.IO.FileInfo.Delete to delete the file, and then System.IO.FileInfo.Refresh() before creating the file again. The Refresh should stop the exception from happening on re-creating the file. Or as nycdan says, use the FileMode.Create enum.

Comment: Wrong; `Refresh()` won't make any difference. `Refresh()` just re-checks the properties in the `FileInfo` instance.